# How to send command in Android via Bluetooth?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, command

I have a problem with send command to Bluetooth chip via Bluetooth.

I have smartphone and BT chip paired good. because I can send "text"

```
BluetoothSPP bt;



void Heat() {
        heat.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        bt.send("Text", true);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

 public void send(String data, boolean CRLF) {
    if(mChatService.getState() == BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        if(CRLF) 
            data += "\r\n"; 
        mChatService.write(data.getBytes());
    }
}
```

Heat is Button on xml file. Heat do Only thise code.

But I don't know how I must remodel to prove send and receive these commands :

↓

```
Send: "$$$"                           Receive: "CMD"    
Send: "S&,0404\r"                       Receive: "AOK"   
Send: "S&,0400\r"                      Receive: "AOK"    
Send: "---\r"                          Receive: "END"
```

I see so send text is successfully because chip have LED which turn-on if accept some information.

Please give me advice or example.

On create

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_autoconnect);
    Log.i("Check", "onCreate");




    bt = new BluetoothSPP(this);

    if(!bt.isBluetoothAvailable()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                , "Bluetooth is not available"
                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }



    bt.setBluetoothConnectionListener(new BluetoothConnectionListener() {

        public void onDeviceConnected(String name, String address) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                    , "Connected to " + name
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onDeviceDisconnected() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                    , "Connection lost"
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onDeviceConnectionFailed() {
            Log.i("Check", "Unable to connect");
        }
    });




    bt.setAutoConnectionListener(new BluetoothSPP.AutoConnectionListener() {
        public void onNewConnection(String name, String address) {

            Log.i("Check", "New Connection - " + name + " - " + address);
        }

        public void onAutoConnectionStarted() {
            Log.i("Check", "Auto menu_connection started");
        }
    });

    TextView btnConnect = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.btnConnect5);
    btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {



            if (bt.getServiceState() == BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                bt.disconnect();
            /**    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                        , "pripojene"
                        , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  **/

               // bt.disconnect();
            } else {
            /**    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                        , "nepripojene"
                        , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  **/
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DeviceList.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, BluetoothState.REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);

            }

        }

    });





    Log.i("Check", "onCreate");

    textStatus = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textStatus2);

    bt = new BluetoothSPP(this);

    if(!bt.isBluetoothAvailable()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()
                , "Bluetooth is not available"
                , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
```

I can comunicate with chip, but i don't know how i can send command. I think you just remodel **bt.send..** If?

Comment: Can you add more code, such as heat and bt variable declarations / library reference?

Comment: I can comunicate with chip, but i don't know how i can send command.  I think you just remodel bt.send.. If?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few research, I found out that you are using `BluetoothSPP` library from https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary.

I don't know why you are using this library or even if you have to use it (like a requirement) but looking at the source code, I can see it's only a wrapper around **Android built-in Bluetooth Classic SDK** for `RFCOMM` communication (also known as `Serial Port Protocol` - **SPP**).

Anyway, all the code relative to sending / receiving data seems to be handled in [BluetoothService](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-BluetoothSPPLibrary/blob/master/library/src/main/java/app/akexorcist/bluetotohspp/library/BluetoothService.java)

What I would recommand is that you create your own wrapper so that you control the **stream** of the ongoing Bluetooth connexion. Then you will be able to send what ever you want because it gets down to simply write **bytes** into the streams and reading them on the other end. However, it is not certain what is the remote `Bluetooh chip` you are using.

If there is some sort of a documentation on what to send, follow it when you send the bytes over the stream.

Again, looking at the source code of the `BluetoothSPP` library, I only see a simple wrapper around Google's **Bluetooth Chat Example**. That's it, no magic here.

Comment: Ok I download this Library, Please Where I need write 
Send: "$$$"                           Receive: "CMD"    
Send: "S&,0404\r"                       Receive: "AOK"   
Send: "S&,0400\r"                      Receive: "AOK"    
Send: "---\r"                          Receive: "END"

Thanks